# Importing Codacy issues to GitHub

Tags: github, software-quality, codacy

I have a lot of issues in my [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) dashboard, but these don't show up in my github repository. I want to import them from Codacy to GitHub to use in repository management.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: normal issues about code quality.

Comment: are you still having this problem or is this question closed?

Comment: that was solved. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are talking about issues reported on Codacy.

It's possible to manually import Codacy issues to GitHub.

Go to `Issues → (Expand the issue) → GitHub → Create comment`.

Would you expect for the issues to be created automatically?

If you have any suggestion on how we could improve this option, please let us know via the support on our website.

Comment: I'm trying make the setup github but still don't work. I create the web hook in github and followed the steps about the URL load and etc. In github the hook looks activated and ok but in codacy still red light and ask to setup github. Wtf! i don't understand whats happen.